# Combine global variables and custom labels in email templates

Tags: visualforce, email-template, customlabel, global-variables

I am trying to dynamically place `{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}` in a custom label for an email template. I want to confirm if these two hypothetical solutions are possible:

#### 1. Include global variables directly in custom label

Consider the following custom label:

> To set up your profile, ask a question, or contribute an answer head to {!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}

Unfortunately in an email template, the {!$...} is placed literally in the email. Is there a way around this?

---

#### 2. Include anchor tag as <apex:param> in a <apex:outputText>

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!$Label.Email_WelcomeToCommunity}">
    <apex:param value="{!$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails}"/> <!-- Pass URL here that's clickable in email -->
</apex:outputText>
```

I've tried the above but get an error: `The value attribute on <apex:outputText> is not in a valid format.`

Comment: Just to clarify, you are indeed using a Visualforce template and not a Plain Text or HTML template, right?

Comment: Correct! This is a Visualforce template.